# Getting ng-model value from template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have ionic modal template, looks like:

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
        .....
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        ...
        <input class="form-input" type="text" ng-model="relation"/>
        ...     
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Inside controller:

```
$scope.resolve = function () {
    console.log('relation', $scope.relation);
}
```

I need to get value from `relation` model inside resolve function, but it is undefined. What the way I can get it?

Thanks for attention!

Comment: Where is the controller or directive that connects your service to your view?

Comment: Please show the whole controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me, Please have a look 
I have updated your Ionic-modal template as

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-content>
        <input class="form-input" type="text" ng-model="test.relation"/>
        <button class="button button-bar button-positive" ng-click="answer()">Click Me</button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Inside your controller please update your code as:

```
$scope.test = {};
$scope.answer = function(){
    console.log($scope.test.relation);
}
```

Please reply back, if you have any queries..

Answer (score 4):

> "If you use ng-model, you have to have a dot in there."

Make your model point to an object.property and you'll be good to go.

The problem which causes this are nested states. You can find more information about this matter [Nested Scopes in AngularJS](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html).

**Controller**

```
$scope.form = {};
$scope.resolve = function () {
    console.log('relation', $scope.form.relation);
}
```

test

**Template**

```
<ion-modal-view>
<ion-header-bar>
    .....
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    ...
    <input class="form-input" type="text" ng-model="form.relation"/>
    ...
</ion-content>
```

Comment: if we don't point to a particular property ? would ngModel not set the radio button as checked? suppose the data of the object is already there in ngModel but not just its property, the whole object with property and value.